# can child BrowserWindow inherit Webcontent event?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have this event handler on my main window.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window')
```

I would like to know if when I create another BrowserWindow, I can have it inherit this event handler or if I have to declare it for every window I create.

Comment: I don't understand: 
`mainWindow` listener will listen all the `"new-window"` events, not only the first.
This is your question? Or you want the listener of `"new-window"` on the newly created `BrowserWindow`?

Comment: @emish89 I'm looking for the second option. Have the newly created BrowserWindow to inherit the behavior on "new-window"

Comment: It's better if you can explain better the problem :) 
You want the listener on ALL the new windows opened? Or only on the last?
You want to remove the first listener and then put it on the second window? 

You can make this in more ways, to find the better we need to know what is the final scope :)

Comment: @emish89 ok so I want to attach this listener to every window I create.

Comment: To only add a new listener, you have to add it when you declare a new BrowserWindow. When you create another new window, the first and the second listener will wake up (2 different listeners).
But I think that it can't be your problem, so maybe I didn't understand...